# Converting from arbitrary, cartesian coordinates to UTM?

Tags: r, gps, coordinates

In my research, we set up a 10m x 10m cartesian grid of stakes in a field (to track animal positions within the grid, at a 1m scale).

We then collected GPS data for a few of our stakes.

So, I have a handful of x, y values with their corresponding UTM Eastings/Northings and many, many more x, y values without GPS data.

Using the reference points that do have GPS data, I'd like to build a script that I can input other x, y values and get the UTM Easings/Northings as output.

I've found a lot of information about converting between UTM and lat/long, but so far can find no information about how to convert between GPS values to arbitrary, cartesian coordinates.

Example reference data:

```
x_coord y_coord Northing     Easting
10      10      4740481.089  709795.318
20      20      4740494.122  709790.115
20      30      4740497.928  709780.943
10      40      4740492.745  709767.865
30      20      4740503.329  709793.934
```

I'd like to be able to input a value like (22, 37) and get the Northing/Easting values.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so you may need to add more information to the question. UTM is metric, so when you can just add x and y to UTM (UTM of your 0,0). Near boundaries you may need to get UTM* -> lat/lng -> UTM. It is permitted to have UTM outside boundaries, so you can calculate lat/lng, in order to renormalize UTM (on correct zone). But your "Northing" "Easting" doesn't seem much UTM (and same y must have same northing).

Comment: Unfortunately, the arbitrary x, y grid does not line up with cardinal directions, so a 10m change in, say, the y-direction of my grid, impacts both the Northing and the Easting values. Does this help?

Comment: That it is not a problem. You can trivially rectify the coordinates with x' and y' with simple trigonometry. With UTM, you are locally on a Cartesian space, with a "metric metric" (first *metric* as unit of SI, the second *metric* as geometrical metric)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but am still not sure how to proceed - I'm not used to spatial data at all, I work primarily with animal behavior. Do you think my first step should be transmuting the (x, y) values to line up with the UTM?

Comment: Yes. I assume it is just a rotation. Then you just have the offset (just addition) to UTM [of point x'=0, y'=0. I do not know what you do, but often flora and fauna studies are done with GIS (good maps, automatic coordinate transformation from local/national/GPS/UTM..., and easy to calculate areas (with a specified density), distances (e.g. to a river), ...).

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is complex, but not unsolvable. The easiest solution is to use GIS. You could plot out the points you have GPS data for then add lines and points between the known points of reference to fill in the gaps.

The next method is to draw (using lines) your entire grid from scratch in GIS, somewhere near your survey location. Then put your GPS points in their proper location. You can them move and rotate the grid till it fits the GPS points.

With both these methods you can then query the National Grid value for each square on your local grid, within GIS.

The alternate step is mathematical and for multiple points a spreadsheet is recommended. In order to convert your local coordinates into National coordinates, you must first establish the difference in angle between the two. Assuming you have a baseline with two GPS readings at either end, subtract the lesser readings from the greater to give you the length of two sides (x and y) of a right-angled triangle, then use the formula *tan to the power of -1 (y/x)* to calculate the difference in angle in degrees.

Now you have the difference in angle, you need to convert all your local grid (cartesian) coordinates into polar coordinates (distance and angle), based on your local grid 0,0. For each grid point use the formula *distance=√(x squared + y squared)* and *angle = tan-1 (y/x)*.

Once you have the angle for each point you simply add or subtract (as appropriate) the difference in angle between the local grid and the national grid.

With the angles corrected you can convert your grid points back into x,y data using the formulas *x=distance × cos(angle)*, *y=distance × sin(angle)*.

The values may come out relative to your first point 0,0, so you may need to add them to your GPS reading for that point to get the final National Grid reading.

You can see why the mathematical method requires a spreadsheet if you are doing this for multiple data points. I've tried it, it works (with the added complication that degrees need to be converted to radians and back again, when using a certain brand of spreadsheet).

So, tips for future fieldwork - don't just use a GPS, use a magnetic compass as well. Ideally establish your grid along compass points, e.g. N-S, E-W. If you can't, use the compass to establish the difference in angle between the two. If you don't need a local grid don't use one, use a baseline and take polar coordinates instead, as it will save a chunk of calculations. Get familiar with GIS, it does all that mathematical work for you under the hood.